# Is it possible to filter key-value pairs of a ThreadContextMap with a Regex?

Tags: java, regex, log4j, log4j2, mdc

I wish to filter certain logs if the "env" key in the `ThreadContextMap` has a value of `prod1` or `qa1`.

I already have something like the following set up:

```
<Console name="prodOutput" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="..."/>
    <Filters>
        <ThreadContextMapFilter onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" operator="or">
            <KeyValuePair key="ENV" value="qa1"/>
            <KeyValuePair key="ENV" value="prod1"/>
        </ThreadContextMapFilter>
    </Filters>
</Console>
```

But this code "hardcodes" the values `prod1` & `qa1`. In the spirit of making the code extensible, I want to filter out those logs if they match the regex of `"prod\d+"` or `"qa\d+"`.

Values that would match these regex's include `"prod1"`, `"qa2"`.

This is because we don't want those certain logs to appear on production & qa environments.

In the `ThreadContextMap`, the key-value pairs we're checking for is `ENV`-`prod1` or `ENV`-`qa1`.

I searched StackOverflow as well as the log4j2 documentation but there doesn't seem to be any mention of how such a thing can be done.

Any ideas on how I can approach this or alternatives?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to find a workaround solution, where I instead apply the regex to the value being inserted into the `ThreadContextMap`

This way, I only ever have to check for 2 values in the `ThreadContextMapFilter`, `prod` & `qa`

This solution is satisfactory enough as it works & meets the requirements we had. For those curious, it looks something like this:

```java
@Value("${env}")
private String environment;
...
// check environment against regex
boolean matchesProdRegex = Pattern.matches(".*prod.*", this.environment);
boolean matchesQaRegex = Pattern.matches(".*qa.*", this.environment);
if (matchesProdRegex ) {
  ThreadContext.put("ENV", "prod");
} else if (matchesQaRegex ) {
  ThreadContext.put("ENV", "qa");
} else {
  ThreadContext.put("ENV", this.environment);
}
```

Consequently in `log4j2.xml`, the `ThreadContextMapFilter` looks something like:

```
<Console name="prodOutput" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
    <PatternLayout pattern="..."/>
    <Filters>
        <ThreadContextMapFilter onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL" operator="or">
            <KeyValuePair key="ENV" value="qa"/>
            <KeyValuePair key="ENV" value="prod"/>
        </ThreadContextMapFilter>
    </Filters>
</Console>
```

Thanks to anyone that took the time to read my post & hope this can be a useful reference for anyone in the future, cheers!